# Initialize common JS functions for performance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to optimize JS performance for a first-time user and SEO, with the goal of minimizing `First Input Delay`. When the home page loads, I initialize common JS functionalities and actions across the site with:

```
<script defer src="~/assets/js/common.js"></script>
```

In `common.js`:

```
$(function () {
    initActions();
}

function initActions() {
 $(document).on("click", "a.modal-link", function (e) {
     var target = $(this).data("target");
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: $(this).data("url"),
         dataType: "html",
         cache: false,
         success: function (response) {
             $(target + " .modal-content").html(response);
             $(target).modal("show");
         }
     }).fail(function () {
         networkError();
     });
 });
 setTimeout(function () {
     $("#successLabel").slideUp("slow");
 }, 8000);
 $(".utcToLocalDate").each(function () {
     $(this).text(moment.utc($(this).data("datetimeutc")).local().format("l"));
 });
```

Is there a best practice to structure JS and declare common functions? I am aware this code is inefficient and I am currently going in circles with iterative improvements.

Comment: I don't see anything inefficient or remotely performance-heavy, is there an actual problem you're experiencing with it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance And based on your nym, you should know. :)